# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable, vector

Tags: python

```
import math
def stats(a):
    mean = sum(a)/len(a)
    var = sum(pow(x-mean,2) for x in a) / len(a)
    std  = math.sqrt(var)
    return (mean, var, std)
print(stats[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

What am I doing wrong? I wanted to create a function that shows mean, var and std without using already existing python functions and I have a trouble with creating a vector. Can you help me guys?

Comment: stats`(`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to comply to Python's function call conventions. @JBernardo pointed it out, and others too (Granny Aching): you are trying to call the function with `[pram1, param2...]`

see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

> The keyword def introduces a function definition. It must be followed
>   by the function name and the **parenthesized list of formal parameters**.

I admit the page does not explicitly tells that call behaves in the same way declaration does. However, it contains lots of examples that fill that gap.

Most of the time, I prefer beginners to write code explicitly:

```
import math
def stats(a : list): # explicitly ask for a list for a
    mean = sum(a)/len(a)
    var = sum(pow(x-mean,2) for x in a) / len(a)
    std  = math.sqrt(var)
    return (mean, var, std)
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] # its a list
mean,var,std= stats(my_list)
print('Mean:{}, var:{}, std:{}'.format(mean,var,std))
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your print statement in the last line, you have: `stats[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

The brackets `[]` are used for *subscripting* (for example selecting an element from a list, a string, or a dictionary)

When using a function, you need to include parentheses. Did you mean `stats([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`?

Comment: yes! import math
def stats(a):
    mean = sum(a)/len(a)
    var = sum(pow(x-mean,2) for x in a) / len(a)
    std  = math.sqrt(var)
    return (mean, var, std)
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(stats(a))